# Udev issue making kernel boot time quite long

Tags: linux, udev

I got an unexpected message during an embedded Linux (3.10.17) boot:

> Populating dev using udev:

After this message is displayed, nothing append for 4 minutes (unnormaly long) and then

> failed

It seems that is error is coming from the S10udev script executed at boot time. As far as I understood, this script fill /dev/ in with every available device.

Do you have any ideas of what is going wrong with udev?

Comment: Do you have a `/var/log/udev` file, and if so what does it say?

Comment: No I don't. But for some reason I got an udev file in /run.